# how can i change backcolor of row in listview

Tags: android, listview, backcolor

- hello frnds i m developing shopping app
- This is my code here i want to change backcolor of row in listview
  when quantity of item is greater than 0,so that i can differ the
  items that bought by customers and items which are not.
- i am using this xml to show my itemlist

  thnk you in advance

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#AED581"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="40"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="Items" />   
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
android:id="@+id/et_searchbar"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:singleLine="true" >
</EditText>
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/et_searchbar" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/bt_search"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/et_searchbar"
android:text="Search"
android:textSize="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>    
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="45"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_Total"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_checkout"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_checkout"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
android:text="0" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:text="Total    Rs:" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_checkout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle"
android:text="Checkout" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add a color attribute your listview

Comment: also add your adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to customize a list is to use an adapter as mentioned in one of the comments.
If it's not clear to you how to use them, refer to [Vogella's Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) on it

Comment: Ok bro ill try it ,thnks